# How can I see "Starred" files in Open/Save dialogues?

Tags: nautilus

If I 'star' files (such as the best photos in a folder) how can I then see which ones are starred when attempting to import or upload them?
The Open Files dialogue in all apps only shows [name, size, type, modified] & the Starred folder on the left is missing.
Is there any way to turn this on?